# WebSockets won't Send data from Vue app - error states 'send' is undefined, Stack: Vue Express Mongo WebSockets

Tags: mongodb, express, vue.js, websocket, undefined

Here is my code that is not working:

```
connectSocket: function () {
  this.socket = new WebSocket('ws://144.0.0.0:8080'); //IP Changed
  this.socket.onopen = function(event) {
    console.log("Connected to the Web Socket Server");
    this.socket.send("Opponent has joined.");
    };
    alert("You're now connected to the server. Be careful out there.");
  this.socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log("Message Received From Server :", event);
    //This is the time to interact with this specific
  };
}
```

The code I am referencing is a method in my vue called upon authentication. I am merely trying to send and receive basic data to the Web Socket Server. However somewhere this is flawed... How could I fix this and maintain authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your event handlers are losing context (`this`) when declared. Use arrow functions to preserve the current context, so the `this` there references the Vue instance:

```
connectSocket: function () {
  this.socket = new WebSocket('ws://144.0.0.0:8080'); //IP Changed
  this.socket.onopen = (event) => {               // changed to arrow function
    console.log("Connected to the Web Socket Server");
    this.socket.send("Opponent has joined.");

    alert("You're now connected to the server. Be careful out there.");
  };
  this.socket.onmessage = (event) => {              // changed to arrow function
    console.log("Message Received From Server :", event);
    //This is the time to interact with this specific
  };
}
```

Also it seemed you had unbalanced curly brackets, so I changed them too. But the important part is really the use of arrow functions.

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I needed,I don't quite understand it but looked it up here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions .
Does the => work because it doesn't have its own "this" whereas if I create a new function that function it has its own "this" associated to it so the parent "this" won't work?